# en visual se me desaparecio el icono de thunder client y ya no puedo utilizarlo,alguie sabe como solucionar eso?

Tags: javascript, rutas, subconsultas

estoy trabajando con thunder client pero de repente el simbolo que aparece en la barra lateral para uno empezar a hacer las consultas desaparecio, ya intente desisntalarlo y nada me funciona

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que es visual??? y que tiene que ver js o subconsultas con tu problema???